# Paging and Router with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I'm not sure how to best implement paging with Angular2 Router.

Say I have a page with a table, with a simple numeric `page` parameter: `/table;page=1`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'table-component',
  template: `
<table> <tr *ngFor="let row of data"><td>{{ row.data }}</td></tr></table>
<button (click)="nextPage()">`
)
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: any[] = [];
  private page: number = 1;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.page = this.route.params.getValue('featuredSearch')
    this.nextPage();
  }
  nextPage() {
    this.page = this.page + 1;
    this.APIService.get('data', this.page)
    .then((data: any[]) => {
      this.data = data;
    })
  }
}
```

(Omitted non-critical data for brewity).

So - how to go to the next page *and* update the route programatically without reloading?
And how to do it with [routerLink], too?